# SQL Server ServerName changed suddenly

Tags: sql-server

I noticed my `@@ServerName` parameter's value has been updated without my knowledge, is there a way to trace back who and when did that change?

I'm running AWS EC2 hosted SQL Server 2016 standard edition.

[image]

Only `@@SERVERNAME` has been changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I noticed my @@ServerName parameter's value has been updated without my knowledge, is there a way to trace back who and when did that change?

and

> Only @@SERVERNAME has been changed

This means that the physical host name didn't change, so I'm not sure why the other answers are pointing you to this.

Most likely this was done via sp_[drop/add]server and will show up if you're using any t-sql auditing or tracing. If you're not, it won't show up in any default logs. You may be able to get lucky and check the log file for master (something such as fn_dblog) but it's highly unlikely you'll get anything useful as the master database uses the simple recovery model and the global variable only reflects changes after a restart of the service.

You may want to implement some type auditing or tracing going forward.

Comment: Final outcome: `(...) implement some type auditing or tracing going forward.`

Answer (score 2):

Let me just echo what Sean said. I just did a repro on this, to be certain and while doing that Sean posted his answer. Anyhow:

@@SERVERNAME returns what is in the sys.servers table (or, since it is a view, the underlying table).

What you see indicates that somebody changed this using sp_dropserver and sp_addserver. I executed the sp_dropserver and sp_addserver procedures and checked the three usual suspects of "default auditing" but couldn't see any trace of these sp's being executed. So, you'd need some own auditing to catch this. Here's my repro (my machine name changed):

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME --Returns 'xyz', my machine name
EXEC sp_dropserver 'xyz'
EXEC sp_addserver 'GammaRay', 'LOCAL'
SHUTDOWN
--Start your SQL Server

SELECT @@SERVERNAME --Returns 'GammaRay'

--check errorlog files, nothing
--check default trace, nothing
--check system_health XE session, nothing

--Reset the name to the old name
EXEC sp_dropserver 'GammaRay'
EXEC sp_addserver 'xyz', 'LOCAL'
SHUTDOWN
```

Update 1:
I was asked to add evidence from manipulation of the underlying tables of sys.servers by looking at log records, using this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ::fn_dblog(NULL, NULL) 
WHERE AllocUnitName IN ('sys.sysxsrvs.cl','sys.syslnklgns.cl')
```

So I did, and the sp_dropserver commands generated these log records (not all columns posted, and sorry about the formatting)

```
LOP_DELETE_ROWS LCX_MARK_AS_GHOST   sys.sysxsrvs.cl
LOP_SET_BITS    LCX_PFS sys.sysxsrvs.cl
LOP_DELETE_ROWS LCX_MARK_AS_GHOST   sys.syslnklgns.cl
LOP_SET_BITS    LCX_PFS sys.syslnklgns.cl
LOP_SET_BITS    LCX_PFS sys.syslnklgns.cl
LOP_SET_BITS    LCX_PFS sys.sysxsrvs.cl
```

And the following sp_addserver generated these:

```
LOP_INSERT_ROWS LCX_CLUSTERED   sys.sysxsrvs.cl
LOP_MODIFY_ROW  LCX_CLUSTERED   sys.sysxsrvs.cl
LOP_MODIFY_ROW  LCX_CLUSTERED   sys.sysxsrvs.cl
LOP_INSERT_ROWS LCX_CLUSTERED   sys.syslnklgns.cl
LOP_MODIFY_ROW  LCX_CLUSTERED   sys.syslnklgns.cl
```

There might be some unrelated noise in above, I should add.

Visually browsing the full output of the query, I couldn't find anything obviously that stood out. I guess you could try to decode columns such as "RowLog contents n" and "Log Records" which contains hexadecimal information.

However, since master is effectively stuck in simple recovery, this information was lost after a restart. I.e., after startup, the query returned zero rows. At least for a proper shutdown.
You could speculate that a hard shutdown might not generate a checkpoint that would truncate the log (but it might be truncated at crash recovery at startup), however, I don't find it likely that a process that renames the server name in the "sys.servers table" would *also* restart the SQL Server instance by forcefully killing the SQL Server process.

Comment: Thanks for the research! Could check if servername change was caught by this query? `SELECT * FROM ::fn_dblog(NULL, NULL) WHERE AllocUnitName IN ('sys.sysxsrvs.cl','sys.syslnklgns.cl')`

Comment: Done @marcin2x4. See my Update 1 above.

Comment: Great thanks! It seems that only way to capture such changes will be having a logging mechanism developed.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can find it on the Server level. As White Owl already mentioned, it is in name of a System Administrator.

> You can determine when a computer name was changed by looking for
> Event ID 6011 from source EventLog in the System log. The 6011 is
> logged at reboot after Event ID 6006 "The Event log service was
> stopped" and before Event ID 6009  and Event ID 6005
> "The Event log service was started."

From [How to Determine When the Computer Name Was Changed](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2366.how-to-determine-when-the-computer-name-was-changed.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

No.

Server name is in hands of System Administrator. So the only way to find when (and why) name was changed is to ask SA. Usually, such big change in the infrastructure is well documented by a lot of discussions and involvement of managers.

But there is no logs for changing system-level variables.